# Word for people who eat out in restaurants/eateries

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there one word for people to substitute "people who eat out in restaurants "?- whether in quick service restaurants, eateries, or high end restaurants.
Terms used in business are preferable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Diner: "someone who is ​eating a ​meal, ​especially in a ​restaurant"

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/diner

plural: diners

business: clientele: "the customers of a shop, bar, or place of entertainment."

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/clientele

Comment: I would think "diners" could also be used to refer to people eating dinner at home, though it does at least imply people being served, rather than just making their own food.

Comment: Here's another source: diner : "a person who is eating dinner in a restaurant"  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diner, and one more source : diner : "someone who is eating a meal at a restaurant" http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/diner

Comment: Those quotes would look so much better in the answer.  Certainly better than the naked fragile links.

Comment: You mean include all the links in the answer? I was afraid of overkill. Shall I?

Comment: if you want to communicate with a user you have to place @ before their username, instead you are always notified whenever someone leaves a comment because you are the author of the post. Btw I think @CandiedOrange's suggestion is a good one.

Comment: CathyGartaganis I mean cited quotes are better than naked links.  For example see [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/318743/76689). BTW, @Mari-LouA has a point about how comment notification works here.

Comment: @everyone : I changed the link in the answer from Google to Oxford dictionary, the original source of the Google link.

Comment: @ CandiedOrange If by cited quotes you mean from a book, I don't know how to find such a link. I can only find a link from a dictionary.

Answer (score 7):

***eater-out***

> A person who frequents restaurants rather than dining at home.
>
> [Neo-Words: A Dictionary of the Newest and Most Unusual Words of Our Time](https://books.google.fr/books?id=qdEUAQAAIAAJ&q=%22eater-outs%22&dq=%22eater-outs%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRvfOo34TMAhWKFSwKHQgPDvkQ6AEIHTAA) by [David K. Barnhart](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Barnhart)

***restaurantgoer***/***restaurant-goer***

> One who goes to or attends restaurants.
>
> 2009 September 6, Seth Schiesel, “All Together Now: Play the Game, Mom”, New York Times: *Sure, the result won’t be of professional caliber (after all, you didn’t go to cooking school, the equivalent of music lessons), but you may have a greater appreciation for the genius who created the dish than the restaurantgoer, because you have attempted it yourself.*
>
> [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/restaurantgoer)
>
> *Out of the dense formations of endless fast food chains, Simon's novelties were to titillate the jaded restaurant goer.* [The Land of Look Behind -Paul Cameron Brown](http://sinemetu1.github.io/poemmm/2810d64f06a54ac95280e3689c22aba1e1a3de88.html)
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/titillate)

Comment: Restaurant-goer can be used to describe a person who habitually eats out, but diner is better to describe someone eating at a specific restaurant at a specific time. Eater-out just sounds weird to me.

Comment: 'eater-out' sounds someone who performs a certain sex act.

Comment: @dwjohnston That's funny, when I first came across words like "oralist" and "carpet cleaner," I thought just about the same.. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/oralist ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Consider

***restaurant patron***

> > a person who buys the goods or uses the services of a business, library, etc.
> >
> > [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patron)

This is a very common business term as it has far reaching implications into other types of business, but when you're at a restaurant, *patron* is very commonly used to refer to the ones eating there.